# Error installing Ubuntu via wubi on Windows 8

Tags: 12.04, wubi, windows-8

I get this error:

```
Couldn't retrieve files from disk image
```

when installing via Wubi from an Ubuntu ISO CD which I previously downloaded.
Here's my [error log file](http://www.mediafire.com/view/qm6apfowu1j1l1b/wubi-12.04.1-rev273.log). It has much information for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're trying to use Wubi with Windows 8 based on this line: `10-13 16:50 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_version2=Windows 8 Pro`

Wubi doesn't work on Windows 8.  It does not work with UEFI either.  Wubi on Windows 8 hasn't ever worked which is one of the reasons they had considered that they stop supporting Wubi at one point with 13.04.

If you want to run Ubuntu inside of Windows 8, you'll have to use virtualbox or some other virtualization solution to run Ubuntu after you've loaded Windows.  Either that, or do an actual dualboot install to the hard drive and install Ubuntu next to Windows on the disk, [as explained here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported).